# Type of Lifeline

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

Is there a way to differ a lifeline from other object instances?

A lifeline has classifier ID, as opposed to other elements on a sequence diagram, but objects on non-sequence diagrams also have the classifier ID.

Thanks!

Comment: You are developing a UML tool  or just try to use UML? If not developing a UML tool, this question has no importance for daily UML usage

Comment: @HippiasMinor, Thanks for reply. I develop a UML tool that has to differ between a lifeline and a regular object. Any ideas?

Comment: The only way to reliably distinguish a sequence lifeline is by seeing which diagram it is on. The same element can appear on multiple diagrams, and will be drawn as a lifeline on sequence diagrams, and differently on other diagrams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @chimp's comment, the right condition to get a lifeline is:

```
if (element.Type.CompareTo("Object") == 0   
   && element.ClassifierID.ToString().Length > 0   
   && diagram.Type.CompareTo("Sequence") == 0)
```